# Evaluating a function that takes numerical arguments over a given list/table

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a given list of some numbers e.g.

```
a = {0, 0.233, 0.65, 1.56};
```

I want to evaluate a function

```
Func[x_?NumberQ,y_?NumberQ,z_?NumberQ]
```

where one variable `z` takes its values from the specified list `a`.

How do I do this in best way ?

Comment: The best way depends on the function, its intended use, and other goals.

Answer (score 4):

Data

```
a = Range[5]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

### Many options

### [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

```
SetAttributes[func, Listable];
func[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ, z_?NumberQ] = f[x, y, z];
func[x, y, a]
(* {func[x, y, 1], func[x, y, 2], func[x, y, 3], func[x, y, 4], func[x, y, 5]} *)
```

### [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
f[x, y, #] & /@ a
(* {f[x, y, 1], f[x, y, 2], f[x, y, 3], f[x, y, 4], f[x, y, 5]} *)
```

### [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
Thread[f[x, y, a]]
(* {f[x, y, 1], f[x, y, 2], f[x, y, 3], f[x, y, 4], f[x, y, 5]} *)
```

### [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
Table[
 f[x, y, z]
 , {z, a}
 ]
(* {f[x, y, 1], f[x, y, 2], f[x, y, 3], f[x, y, 4], f[x, y, 5]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed, known values `x1` and `y1` for the first variables, then how about the following?

```
a={0, 0.233, 0.65, 1.56};
Func[x1,y1,#]&/@a
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Define your function with just $x$ and in the body refer to `x[[7]]` (or multiple entries, or whatever components of $x$ are used as $z$).

Comment: Thank you !! I need the argument i of x[[i]]  to run from 1... length[A]. So I need to create a table in the end which implements the following:  B = Table[Func[x0,y0,z] : z goes from A[1] to A[N] ].